Explicit construction of integers with prescribed digit sum and residue class conditions
Let $q\geq 2$ be an integer, and $p,m\in \mathbb{N}$. Also, let $S_q$ be the function sum of digits in base $q$. If $\gcd(m,q-1)=1$, a result of Gelfond establishes that the set of integers $\{n: S_q(n)\equiv a \mod{m}\}$ is equally distributed in residue classes $\mod{p}$ for every $a\in \mathbb{Z}_m$.
In particular, this shows that for any $a\in \mathbb{Z}_m$ and $b\in \mathbb{Z}_p$, there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $S_q(n)\equiv a\mod{m}$ and $n\equiv b \mod{p}$.
I was wondering if there is a simple way to construct integers that satisfies these conditions? I am particularly interested in the case $a=1$ and $b=0$. Many thanks!

Note you can explicitly write out the sum of all base $q$ digits for $n$ as follow: $$S_q(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{q^k}\right\rfloor-q\left\lfloor\frac{n}{q^{k+1}}\right\rfloor=n-(q-1)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{q^k}\right\rfloor=n-(q-1)\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor\log_q(n)\rfloor}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{q^k}\right\rfloor$$

@EthanSplaver thanks for your comment. I've tried by taking n=kp, but it is not very clear to me how to conclude the existence of k such that the sum of digits is 1 mod m.

Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/482390/explicit-construction-of-integers-with-prescribed-digit-sum-and-residue-class-co
